# How to append columns aligned with a loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Recently I've been trying to build a data frame out of the content of 3 excel files (xlxs). I made a `for` loop to look for the files and then unite them.

```
import pandas as pd
    import glob
    f_list = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\*.xlsx")  
    all_data = pd.DataFrame()             
    for f in f_list:                       
       df = pd.read_excel(f)             
       all_data = all_data.append(df , sort=True, ignore_index=True)
```

The 3 tables were made of a single column of a letter (a, b, and c). Therefore, the expected result was a dataframe with 3 columns with lines like: a b c.

```
[Result of the code][Image]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWzti.png

What am I getting wrong? I must say I'm totally noob with Python and I'm just strating with pandas.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you actually want all those nulls? Normally we'd do `all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df], axis=1)` to append the columns, but that would make a *dense* Dataframe instead of the *sparse* one in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need create `list of DataFrames` called `all_data` by list comprehension or loop and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by columns with parameter `axis=1`:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

f_list = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\*.xlsx")  
#list comprehension 
all_data = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in f_list]  

#same like loops solution
all_data = []            
for f in f_list:                       
    df = pd.read_excel(f)             
    all_data.append(df)
```

---

```
df = pd.concat(all_data, axis=1)
```